# Generic select concatenation all columns from a table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need a generic way to perform this kind of query:

```
select t.column1+t.column2+t.column3+....+t.column25 from myTable t;
```

So what I'm looking for would be something like this:

```
select concat(*) from myTable t;
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: unless you use dynamic sql there is no way,its better to manually write all columns ,unless you have many queries of this type

Comment: @TheGameiswar, yes I have to loop throw all tables in data base, So dynamically is the only way??

Comment: @Chanukya no not necessary.

Comment: That you are asking for a generic way to do this anti-relational operation suggests there's something really quite wrong with your database design...

Comment: @AakashM, well I didn't expose my aime, but i have 3 same schema data bases with different transactionnel data witch will be merged into 1 central data base, and I need to ensure that data from the three data bases exist in the central one ,and I have to go throw over than a 100 table (each data base) to compare data. My be it's a silly idea i had,but for the moment i don't have other

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DECLARE @Names VARCHAR(8000) 
DECLARE @SQLQuery AS NVARCHAR(500)
SELECT @Names = COALESCE(@Names + ', ', '') + name 
FROM sys.columns WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('tablename')

SET @SQLQuery = 'SELECT CONCAT(' + @Names + ') FROM tablename '
EXECUTE(@SQLQuery)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @TableName SYSNAME = 'dbo.MyTable'

SELECT STUFF
(
    (
        SELECT ', ' + [name]
        FROM [sys].[columns]
        WHERE [object_id] = OBJECT_ID(@TableName)
        ORDER BY [column_id]
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
    ).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)')
    ,1
    ,1
    ,''
);
```

It is concatenating the columns depending on their creation order. It's ok for wide tables (tables with many columns).